# Testing a method using GTest?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, googletest

I have a method for ex : Func(), where Func returns a structure object.

```
    somestruct Func()
    {

    }

    struct somestruct
    {
    int a;
    int response;
    };
```

Depending upon the value of parameter response my test will pass or Fail.

if response member returns 0 my test gets passed.

```
    TEST(Testcase, Testcasename)
    {
    somestruct obj;
    obj = Func()
    EXPECT_EQ(0, obj.response);
    }
```

But if response parameter value is 1 or 2 or 3, than i need to invoke other methods Func1() or Func2() & if the value is 3 than Func2() & Func3() both should be invoked. If these methods call returns successfully , than call to Func() will return 0 as response.

I dont know how should i write test case statements "EXPECT_EQ etc..." for such kind of method, kindly help me with your inputs.

Comment: read about parametrized tests. https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests

Comment: Parameterized tests are no good when you have different paths for each input. What exactly are you trying to achieve? How is response parameter obtained in unit under test? Why a given obtained parameter must be followed by a calls to different functions?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen the value of the response parameter is provided by a remote server, If for example: response value 2 is received than i have to update some certificates in my biometric device. Basically Func() check's if my device is up to date with the latest changes.

Comment: It seems to me that your tests are inversed. You should mock the remote server's responses in order to test your code reaction. (and remote server should be tested as well ofc, but separately). So, if I understand correctly, if your class receives `response` equal to 1, then it should call `Func1()`? Then that's how you should test it. Feed your class with `somestruct` having `response` equal to `1` and mock a call to `Func1`, so you can capture them.

Comment: Can you provide some example please.